# Trying to consume a wsdl with all xsd having elementFormDefault=“qualified” set, but still the request generated does not has the children prefixed

Tags: .net-core, wcf-binding

I have a .net Core 2.2 project, consuming a wsdl where all xsd have elementFormDefault="qualified" set, however the request generated does not has its children prefixed

I have tried setting attributeFormDefault="qualified", and surprisingly it works. I also tried consuming the wsdl from .net framework 7.2, but the prefixes were still missing.

Please check the image for comparison
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhyvO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I extended the header class and added namespaces. Such as :

```
public partial class FabriCXHeaderType
  {
      [XmlNamespaceDeclarations()]
      public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlsn
      {
          get
          {
              XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
              xsn.Add("h", "http://www.cathaypacific.com/infra/fabricxheader/v2");
              return xsn;
          }
          set
          {
          }
      }
  }
```